# div expand over another div when set padding

Tags: html, css

When I set a padding for div .detalhes, the .detalhes box expand over the div .seta. Take a look at:
http://jsfiddle.net/XdfCp/

What can I do to resolve this? My detalhes div has witdh of 100%. I want it consider the padding to calculate the width needed.

Comment: Read up on the [box model](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the width, and don't float the div. http://jsfiddle.net/XdfCp/3/

```css
#ListaEventosPorMes .detalhes{
    display: block; 
    background-color: #722827;          
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

If you're learning CSS, take some time to understand how floats work, and try to avoid them when there are alternatives. Do not just float an element to "fix" something, it may have nasty consequences.

Comment: You've used xfloat. What does it mean?

Comment: It doesn't exist. I added the `x` to check the effect of removing the float. Fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/XdfCp/3/

Comment: Also, you don't need `display:block` either. Divs have `display:block` by default.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the element you have added padding to has a width set of 100%, this means that the padding will get added onto this which will expand the element over .seta.

Best bet is to alter your width and set the padding as % so something like width:90%; padding: 5% or set a max-width.

something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/XdfCp/2/